# Templated function with defaulted std::function parameter causes symbol [...] already defined

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I just ran into something somewhat odd.
I wonder if it's a bug, and if not I hope someone can explain the issue.

My issue is that when I create a templated function which takes an `std::function` as a defaulted parameter, I can only create one template instantiation of this function, otherwise I get an error.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <functional>

template<bool B>
void wut(std::function<void()> f = []() {})
{
    f();
}

int main() {
    wut<false>(); // works
    wut<false>(); // still works
    wut<true>();  // error
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/VlVcUv

When compiling this code I get the following error:

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:28: Error: symbol `_ZNSt14_Function_base13_Base_managerIUlvE_E10_M_managerERSt9_Any_dataRKS3_St18_Manager_operation' is already defined
{standard input}:127: Error: symbol `_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFbvEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data' is already defined
```

Comment: intuitively I would say that you cannot have two different functions with same name and same signature. On the other hand I dont know if the standard actually does reuire `wut<true>` and `wut<false>` to be two different functions (hence I deleted my answer)

Comment: Locally I'm using GCC 7.3.0. I just tried compiling with clang 6.0.0 and it works. So it seems I've stumbled upon a GCC bug.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GCC 7.3.0 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dRSrUw Otherwise with newest builds of GCC, Clang and MSVC, it compiles fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce with GCC 6.3 either (which Ideone says it's using).  Very strange.

Comment: Hmm very interesting! The precise compiler version I'm using is g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

Comment: I can reproduce with g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

Comment: As I pointed out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52969201/1708801) you can use Wandbox, which keeps up to date with compiler versions and this looks like it only effect gcc 7.3 and below.

Comment: @DeiDei it is a linker issue, so godbolt won't show it, but as I noted in my answer this is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gcc bug (which looks fixed after version 7.3) we can see this by looking at section [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]p9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#9):

> A lambda-expression appearing in a default argument shall not
>   implicitly or explicitly capture any entity. [Example:
>
> ```
> void f2() {
> int i = 1;
> void g1(int = ([i]{ return i; })()); // ill-formed
> void g2(int = ([i]{ return 0; })()); // ill-formed
> void g3(int = ([=]{ return i; })()); // ill-formed
> void g4(int = ([=]{ return 0; })()); // OK
> void g5(int = ([]{ return sizeof i; })()); // OK
> }
> ```
>
> —end example]

As an alternative to IDEOne, you can use Wandbox which keeps up to date with gcc and clang versions, see [your example live there](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kLvUJqLWwLhF4R9K).

Comment: I was about to argue that these examples (g4, and g5) are different from mine. Then I tried modifying my example to be more like g5 and got the exact same error message: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VGuqQBUZMxyCiV4d I think we can close this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a compiler bug.

However using lambdas in header files is fraught with ODR issues.  So I'd avoid it.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template<auto X>
struct always_return {
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...)const{ return X; }
};

template<bool B>
void wut(std::function<bool()> f = always_return<false>{})
{
```

Or in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
template<class T>
struct always_return_t {
  T t;
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...)const{ return t; }
};
template<class T>
always_return_t<typename std::decay<T>::type> always_return(T&&t) {
  return {std::forward<T>(t)};
}
template<bool B>
void wut(std::function<bool()> f = always_return(false)){
```